# Cygwin find command with `-printf` sometimes runs out of memory with `memory exhausted` and fails

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cygwin, find

I am running `find` from a batch file because I need the result in batch context.

Running `c:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe . -type d -name "SubDir" -printf "%%T^@^!%%p\n" > temp.txt` yields `/usr/bin/find: memory exhausted`.

If I remove the printf, it works fine, but I would like to be able to sort the output.

If there is a better way to sort nested subdirs based on date and time, that would be fine too.

**Edit:**

When I run this batch file from an already open **cmd** window, it works.  But when I double click the batch file, **find** uses up all my ram and prints `memory exhausted`.

Maybe I messed up the escape characters `%` and `^` but I followed Rob's table found here https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: what is your expected result ? Running from CMD, I obtain only a repetition of `%T^@^!%p`

Comment: I expect it to match the 2 subdirs that I have in sub directories that are named “SubDir” with time in front.   Instead it consumes 13 gigs of memory before stopping.